# How to retain input text field value into some memory at the time of ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am working on dynamically updating the HTML table on clicking the drop-downs

- I have an drop-down with HTML table
- The drop-down having 10-15 options but here I am showing only 3 i.e `All`,`Cat1`,`Cat2` because of minimal code
- initially I am populating table for `All` categories
- Suppose user clicks on `Cat1` option and html table populates according to that my html table have an input field named as `Quantity` which has initial value as `0`.
- Now user input something into input field i.e `Quantity` and didn't click on save button, and clicks on `Cat2` now new html table populates for `Cat2` then user input something into there also, after typing some inputs their user goes back to `Cat1` option again, but now the input field value is refreshed and are `0` now, not the one user entered

So my question is how can I store the values into some local memory or variable so that if user go back to the first drop-down data it should show what user have entered not `0`.

What I have done till now

```js
var tableData = [{
    "Item Code": "1001",
    "Item Name": "Beverages",

    "Quantity": ""

  },
  {
    "Item Code": "2003",
    "Item Name": "Juices",

    "Quantity": ""
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1004",
    "Item Name": "Soups",

    "Quantity": ""

  },
  {
    "Item Code": "2005",
    "Item Name": "Cookies",

    "Quantity": ""

  },

]

function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];

      if (tableData[i]['Item Code'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData[i]['Item Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableData[i]['Quantity'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "center";
        quantityField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        quantityField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        quantityField.setAttribute('type', 'number');
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
        /* console.log(quantityField) */
      }
      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTable(tableData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form action="InsertQuantityIndent" method="post" id="form1">
  <div class="row position-relative">

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h5>Category</h5>
      <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
        <option>All</option>
        <option>Cat1</option>
        <option>Cat1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class=" w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="save">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>

  </div>
</form>
```

Above snippet is showing the initial output when page loads. After user click on other drop-down let say `Cat1` I am making an AJAX call on `onchange` event to cat data where category= selected category

```
$('#CategoryName').on('change', function() {
        var selectedOption =this.value;
          $.ajax({
                async: true,
                url : "ItemCategoryWiseFilter",
                method : "POST",
                data : {
                       categoryName :selectedOption,        
                     },                          
            });
          $.ajax({
                 async: true,
                url : "ItemCategoryWiseFilter",
                method : "GET",
                dataType : "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                                              
                success : function(tableData) {                                                         
                      addTable(tabledata);
                    }
            }); 

        });
```

For more understanding, here is my back end code

```
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            lhm = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
            itemCode = resultSet.getString("itemcode");
            itemName = resultSet.getString("itemname");
            lhm.put("Item Code", itemCode);
            lhm.put("Item Name", itemName);
            lhm.put("Quantity", "0");
            mainList.add(lhm);
            str = gson.toJson(mainList);

        }
```

What is my approach:

- I think of making ajax call and send the input field data to server then on next ajax call when user change or goes back to same drop-down should call that data
- But initially table is showing for all category and after that user clicks on `Cat1` it shows `Cat1` data and for first time the quantity should be `0` after that user will edit and go to other drop-down
- My issue is how can I send data back to server what user has input at `Cat1` category and show the same data when user comes back to `Cat1` again.

Comment: Do you _need_ this particular value on the server in the first place? If you only want to remember it so that you can populate the field with the correct value again _before_ the user submits this form, but have no interest in actually storing these “interim choices” … then why send it to the server at all?

Comment: @misorude when user clicks on save i am saving all the data with quantity entered by user into my db

Comment: does your page reload or redirect to the different page on click of save?

Comment: @Jackson yup on clicking save i am  saving the data to db and populating new table of other page

Comment: Why is this making _two_ AJAX requests to the same URL? Make the POST request, and have the server respond to _that_ with the data you need. Since these are async requests it is not even guaranteed that the server has processed your POST request already before you make the GET request.

Comment: @misorude by first ajax i am sending the `categoryname` to server and using that into my query and that result i am populating via `Get` request on `UI` that all is happening on `onchange` of select

Comment: @Jackson yup it reloads and redirect to different page

Comment: My question was _why_ you do it this way, why do you not just have the server answer the POST request directly with that data that you need? AGAIN: These requests are async, so there is no guarantee that they happen in this order. Your server might receive the GET request first, answer that with _old_ data, and only update the data on the server afterwards, when it processes the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

1. On page load, populate the categories and the qty values from backend [maybe in form-data or an ajax to retrieve the value ].
2. Create a JSON object in the Javascript and populate that whenever the user changes the category

[image]

3. write a script and populate the values to the jsonObject on input focus out.

   ```
   $( "input[type='text']" ).focusout(function() {

        var itemId = get the item id;
        var catValue = get the cat value  //$('#CategoryName option:selected").text();
        dataObject.catValue.itemId = $(this).val();
   //dataObject => getting the dataobject created in the javascript

   // dataObject.catValue => will give the category lik dataObject."All" or dataObject."cat1"

   // dataObject.catValue.itemId  => will give the property.=> dataObject."cat1"."1001"

   });
   ```
4. on click of save => pass this json object to the backend

Comment: how can i make different json into javascript on category change ?

Comment: can you please elaborate me what you doing..because right now i am very confused

Comment: how this one is related to my problem.. my issue is if user enter some thing into input field of `Cat1` and goes to `Cat2` and comes aging to `Cat1` then what he had entered into cat1''s input field should not get refreshed with other data....and there is no work of save now it will be used at the end to save data into db thats it

Comment: whenever user change the dropdown, get the category object from dataObject and populate it. no need to have any ajax

Comment: ookk..can you give me the full code so that i ll understand where i have to write what..actually i am very confused right now thats why pleas help

Comment: @manishthakur: please do not ask for free labour here (or indeed anywhere on the web). Asking professionals for free work is not respectful of people's time, and moreover won't teach you much. If you are really struggling with a concept, then have patience with yourself, and embark on a program of formal study.